# Delete rows of a CSV (file) with awk

Tags: csv, awk

Seawater_dat.csv:

```
submission ID, NAME, COUNT, Location
S34575265, Snow Goose, 12, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, X, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, 1, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, 1, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, X, Pt. Pinos
```

What I need to do is remove every row that contains X value associated with count through awk.

Code that I tried:

```
$ awk -F ‘$3X’ Seawatch_dat.csv
```

It resulted in error stating unexpected character '.'
I am assuming my command prompt is incorrect.
What I expected to happen was that every row containing X would be deleted by running code.

Expected Result:
Seawater_dat.csv:

```
submission ID, NAME, COUNT, Location
S34575265, Snow Goose, 12, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, 1, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, 1, Pt. Pinos
```

Comment: Change the smart quotes, `‘` and `’`, to normal ASCII single quotes `'` to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try:

```
awk -F, '$3 !~ /X/' Seawater_dat.csv
```

As a side note, the file is *not* a csv file in a strict sense as it includes
unnecessary whitespaces after commas.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider your file to be CSV then you want to eliminate rows with  `X` in 3rd column, you might use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.csv` content be

```
submission ID, NAME, COUNT, Location
S34575265, Snow Goose, 12, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, X, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, 1, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, 1, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, X, Pt. Pinos
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}$3!=" X"' file.csv
```

gives output

```
submission ID, NAME, COUNT, Location
S34575265, Snow Goose, 12, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, 1, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, 1, Pt. Pinos
```

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that field separator is `,` then select rows where 3rd column value (`$3`) is not equal (`!=`) string  `X`

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty `awk` procedure if you *know your data* does not contain `X` in a field on its own anywhere else but field 3, and fields always begin with a single space:

```
awk '!/, X, /' seawater_dat.csv
```

*output*

```
S34575265, Snow Goose, 12, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, 1, Pt. Pinos
S34575294, Snow Goose, 1, Pt. Pinos
```

The procedure uses a single pattern (`//`) to (default) print records (lines) that do not (`!`) contain `, X,`

Answer (score -1):

According to the sample data in your question, you want to keep only those lines from the CSV file that do **not** contain a capital *X*.

```
awk '!/X/ {print}' Seawater_dat.csv
```

Refer to this [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/AJR)
(Note that you have to copy the contents of file `Seawater_dat.csv` to the **Stdin Inputs** field before clicking the **Execute** button.)

Comment: That would fail if you changed the 2nd field `Snow Goose` on line 1 of the input to `Charles Xavier`. The OP said that want to find `every row that contains X value associated with count` and `count` is just the 3rd field.

Comment: @EdMorton I did state that my solution is based on the sample data in the question.